# What's the name of convergently-divergent directed, categorized nodes?

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, terminology

I'm looking for existing terminology, or make up my own, new terminology.

What's the name of a graph that has:

- nodes which are divergent in one direction, convergent in the other
- edges that are directed
- nodes which are of a specific type or category

Does that still count as "canonical" ? Or is it "hyperboloid"?

Or simply convergently-divergent directed, categorized nodes?

Sorry for being a total amateur, I hope someone can point me in the right direction.[image]

Comment: Where is the terminology in your images from? These terms are not typically used by graph theorists (and in fact, I am getting zero Google results for "convergently directed node"). In graph theory, directed edges are typically a one-to-one relationship; you could certainly have several nodes $u_1, u_2, \dots, u_k$ each with a directed edge to the same node $v$, but those would be different edges.

Comment: Good question, where did I get this from lol... I'm just taking a shot in the dark based on some stuff I found previously! https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Different-types-of-graphs-and-their-corresponding-adjacency-matrix-representations-The_fig1_347300725  
Thank you for pointing out that "convergently directed node" has no search results, and that graphs usually have a 1 to 1 relationship! That's actually very helpful for my work! :-) I appreciate the input

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_canonization

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)

Comment: In the context of graph canonization, a "canonical graph" is not a special type of graph. Take any type of graph with whatever special features you like (directed or undirected edges, colors on nodes, etc.), and one can come up with a rule to put such graphs into a canonical form.

Comment: It looks a bit like you're mixing ideas used in graph theory, ideas used in software design, ideas used in database analysis, and so forth, without paying attention to where they came from. All of these sources draw similar diagrams where they connect things with lines, but they care about very different problems (and often make hidden assumptions that might not be true in other situations), so pulling terminology from all of them at once is very confusing - not to mention when two of these sources use the same word with a very different meaning, like "canonical".

Comment: @MishaLavrov you're right, I'm mixing up several things here from different fields... Thank you for taking the time to provide feedback and share your thoughts! :)